# How container restricts the memory allocated to it?

Tags: docker

while running docker with -m option memory provided as 10MB, but in C application malloc of 64MB is  successful. Do any configuration needs to be done for container so that memory provided restricts memory allocation?

Comment: Did you try using those 64MB?

Comment: Yes, calloc fails to allocate memory of 64MB and binds to restriction